# How should I use my custom windows based build tools docker image from aws ECR repo as environment in my CDK build script

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-sdk-js, aws-cdk, amazon-ecr

I am creating aws codepipeline for windows WPF application for this I have already created custom docker image which has VS2017 build  tools in it and this image will work as build environment to build all my .Net framework related applications.
I have successfully created aws pipeline from UI i.e. aws console, but I am trying to create CDK stack for this same thing using typescript
below is my code

```
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core'); 
import codecommit = require('@aws-cdk/aws-codecommit'); 
import codebuild = require('@aws-cdk/aws-codebuild'); 
import codepipeline = require('@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline'); 
import codepipeline_actions = require('@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions'); 
import s3 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-s3'); 
import { Repository } from '@aws-cdk/aws-codecommit'; 

export class CdkClickOnceAppPipelineStack extends cdk.Stack { 
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) { 
    super(scope, id, props); 

    const code = codecommit.Repository.fromRepositoryName(this, 'WPFAppRepo','WPFClickOnceApp'); 
    const cdkBuild = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this,'CdkBuild',{ 
     description: 'AWS build project for .Net WPF click once application', 
     environment: {buildImage:codebuild.WindowsBuildImage.WIN_SERVER_CORE_2016_BASE} 
    }); 

  } 
}
```

In this code I can specify `environment` as `WIN_SERVER_CORE_2016_BASE` which is the base image provided by aws but I want to specify my custom docker image which I have ready in my aws ECR repository.

Can someone help me with this I could not find documentation for windows .Net framework stuff on internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do define an image like this:

```
 const ecrRepo = awsEcr.Repository.fromRepositoryArn (this,[repo Id],'arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:[account Id]:repository/RepoName');

const cdkBuild = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this,'CdkBuild',{ 
     description: 'AWS build project for .Net WPF click once application', 
     environment: {buildImage:codebuild.WindowsBuildImage.fromEcrRepository(ecrRepo,'latest')} 
    });
```

its here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-codebuild-readme.html

Comment: Thanks @Arun  I did find .fromEcrRepository() method but I saw it's return type in docs in my VS code IDE it showed me "@returns A Linux build image from ECR repository" and mine is windows based custom image so I did not use this. I will try using this and will get back to you . Thanks again.

Comment: thanks for the edit, now it makes more sense to the question